# Core Data Predicate to-many to-many performance involving predicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In an application that I have just written I have an object relationship that could be written as BaseIngredient <<--->> Recipe.

The reason for this relationship is to improve the performance of what was the existing underlying model which had about 3 table in-between BaseIngredient and Recipe.

The predicate that I had written before was

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(ingredients, $i, ANY $i.ingredientSection.recipe IN %@).@count > 0", self.recipesFilter];
```

which traversed several objects.

I replaced it with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY recipes IN %@", recipes];
```

and it is significantly slower.

As a bit of information this predicate is part of an NSFetchedResultsController that is handed the recipes from a different tables NSFetchedResultsController. Does anyone have an explanation of why this would be slower and how to make in fast?

Comment: The argument for your predicate format string should be recipes, not recipe IDs.

Comment: I've already tried it both ways.

Comment: Now we know that your input array is wrong, or the underlying data you are searching. Did you check those?

Comment: Neither. The input array is just fine and works, it works functionally, just not as fast as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

I think your predicate can be improved. The correct usage of `IN` is:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipes in %@", selectedRecipes];
```